# Why is there not a function in C that returns size of memory allocated pointed to by a pointer?

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

After searching around for a bit on how deallocation (via `free`) after allocation (via something like `malloc`) works, I'm left puzzled.

Reading around, sources say that when memory is allocated, it actually has one word more allocated which stores the size of the allocation. This is what `free` uses to deallocate the memory. But with this information arises another question which I can not find the answer to anywhere: If the size of memory allocated is stored somewhere, why is there not a function or method in C that can give us the size of memory allocated via something like `malloc`?

Comment: You could parse the heap yourself or create a `malloc` wrapper with a `struct` that has address and length.

Comment: Questions about why something doesn't exist can only be answered by those who were involved in the initial design of the language. But generally, either they didn't even consider such a feature, or the feature conflicted with some other design goal. I'm guessing the former, since code that calls `malloc` certainly knows how much memory it requested. On the other hand, if it's the latter, I can think of several design goals that would conflict with this feature.

Comment: "it actually has one word more allocated which stores the size of the allocation. " --> Storing the size per allocations not specified, Other possibilities exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard only specifies the functions needed to allocate and free memory.  This means that how the heap is managed is a implementation detail of the standard library on your system.  How Linux does it is likely very different from Microsoft's implementation.

That being said, sometimes these implementations expose additional functions that expose the internal state of the heap.  For example, Linux has a function called `malloc_usable_size` which is passed a pointer to allocated memory and returns the number of bytes that may be written at that address.

Still, it's best not to depend on system specific functions like that.  Your program should have some way of keeping track of how much space a malloc'ed block of memory points to.